# Facebook sign up using django allauth tastypie

Tags: django, facebook, tastypie, django-allauth

I am working on a mobile app that allows users to sign up via Facebook. Once I receive the access token from FB, I send it to the Django backend.

I am using tastypie and django-allauth.

How can I use django-allauth to create the new user/social account using the access token?

I am using this code to login with already registered FB accounts, but when I try to signup with it, an error is raised that says:

> 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'email'

```
def facebook_login(self, request, **kwargs):
        self.method_check(request, allowed=['post'])

        data = self.deserialize(request, request.body, format=request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'applicaton/json'))

        if "access_token" not in request.body:
            data = {"message": 'missing access token'}
            return self.error_response(request, data, response_class=http.HttpBadRequest)

        access_token = data.get('access_token', '')

        try:
            app = SocialApp.objects.get(provider="facebook")
            token = SocialToken(app=app, token=access_token)

            login = fb_complete_login(app, token)
            login.token = token
            login.state = SocialLogin.state_from_request(request)
            ret = complete_social_login(request, login)

            #if we get here we've succeeded
            return self.create_response(request, {
                'email': request.user.email,
                'api_key': request.user.api_key.key
                }, HttpAccepted)

        except Exception as ex:
            data = {"message": ex}
            return self.error_response(request, data, response_class=http.HttpBadRequest)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code actually works, The problem was setting SOCIALACCOUNT_AUTO_SIGNUP=false and that was causing the error.